# table within bootstrap panel dividing lines going from thick to thin

Tags: html, css, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

That is a screencap or a table inside of a bootstrap panel.the code is below:

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Mon</th>
                        <th>Tue</th>
                        <th>Wed</th>
                        <th>Thu</th>
                        <th>Fri</th>
                        <th>Sat</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                        {
                            var meetingTime = meeting.MeetingTimes.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MeetingDay == (DayOfWeek)i);
                            <td>
                                @if (meetingTime != null)
                                {

                                    @meetingTime.MeetingTime.ToString("h:mmt")<br />
                                    foreach (var type in meetingTime.MeetingTypes)
                                    {
                                        <a data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" title="@type.LongName">@type.ShortName</a><br />
                                    }
                                }
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Is this just a bug or am I doing something wrong?  the horizontal line on top of the header row ends and the line below it goes from thick to thin at about the same place.

The screenshot was taken from inside chrome. but the same thing happens inside IE, and inside chrome on my phone.  I believe they are the most recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had different numbers of columns in the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.  forgot to include Sunday! oops.